# How to write a snippet which content is depended on some expanded field?

Tags: emacs, elisp, code-snippets, yasnippet

I try to write a snippet to achieve this:

Expandable field:

```
<something I don't know how to write>(my_class#($1))
```

Expected result:

If $1 is empty:

```
`my_factory_utils(my_class)
```

If $1 is not empty:

```
`my_factory_param_utils(my_class#(<$1 content>))
```

Could anyone give me a clue about how could I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use transformations on mirrors

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: testsnip
# key: testsnip
# --
${1:$(if (zerop (length yas-text)) "my_factory_utils" "my_factory_param_utils")}(my_class${1:$(if (zerop (length yas-text)) "" "#")}$1)
```

See [docs](http://capitaomorte.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html).